# How do I replace a dependency of a dependency in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm working with a Java project that is using a library that has a dependency on a library with a security vulnerability. Unfortunately, the updated version of the vulnerable library does not have the same group. Basically, the library `org.reallyuseful.library:usefulstuff:1.0` depends on `org.vulnerable.dependency:dependency:1.0`, but the vulnerability has been fixed in `org.secure.dependency:dependency:1.1`.

In Gradle, how do I tell `usefulstuff:1.0` to use `org.secure.dependency:dependency:1.1` instead of `org.vulnerable.dependency:dependency:1.0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can explicitly declare a dependency on `org.secure.dependency:dependency:1.1` like `implementation("org.secure.dependency:dependency:1.1")` in your build file. The dependency version you specified will be have precedence over the transitive dependency.

Another option might be to specify an `exclude` rule to make sure that the dependency is not brought in (see [example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies))

I think the best pattern would we to use the tools provided from the [*Dependency Management*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) section of the user guide. In this case, you should be able to use the `resolutionStrategy` API. You can substitute the desired dependency for the originally requested one.

This example configures a resolution rule for every `Configuration`:

```groovy
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    if (details.requested.group == "org.vulnerable.dependency"
        && details.requested.name == "dependency"
        && details.requested.version == "1.0") {
      details.useTarget("org.secure.dependency:dependency:1.1")
    }
  }
}
```

The Gradle user guide also has an [example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:blacklisting_version) where only the version is changed, and an [example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:module_substitution) which is very similar to the above snippet (and your use case).